# React simple code error: Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babel-loader

I am implemmenting `react.js` in an existing app.

I just added the `webpack` and a simple `App` component to check initially how it works, and am getting error:

```
Target container is not a DOM element.
```

Exactly it says in the console:

```
Error: Minified React error #200; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=200 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
```

which leads to the above message as error #200.

The view is just simple:

```
<script src="~/dist/index.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

and the component:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const App = () => <div>Hello world!</div>;

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

The webpack just simple setup:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        index: "./app/index.js"
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../dist"),
        filename: "[name].js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                },
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/ //excludes node_modules folder from being transpiled by babel. We do this because it's a waste of resources to do so.
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps, the script element should go after the div element in your html file.

Comment: Silly me... I think I worked too long today lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `Target container is not a DOM element.`
>
> ```
> <script src="~/dist/index.js"></script>
> <div id="root"></div>
> ```

The bundled script was run before the div you are attaching to was rendered. Simply reorder the script element after the div:

```
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="~/dist/index.js"></script>
```